# Silent push notification for web oneSignal

Tags: node.js, push-notification, onesignal, web-push

Can I use silent web push notification using oneSignal? need to update some chunks of data without prompting the notification to user. I went through the documentation but couldn't find any useful data in it though.
I am using Nest Js as BE and React Js as FE.

Comment: Let me make sure I'm understanding. You don't want to show the OneSingal prompt or the actual push notification? Can you provide me an example please so I can assist you better

Comment: Yes, I want to update the data in the background but don't want the notification popup prompt to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting my answer late, I sent a message to the onesignal team on their website's Support chat option. This is the reply I get, latest of July 20th, 2021. May be in future, they may integrate this feature, but unfortunately not available now.

> You cannot send notifications on web without displaying a
> notification to the user.
>
> You can add additional Data to the notification and access that data
> in the notificationDisplay event.
>
> Here is the docs on this:
> https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk#section-notification-display
>
> Thanks

Ana From Onesignal (just for reference)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation I see from the [API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/edit-tags-with-external-user-id), you can edit the external user id data tags.

Now, using a silent web push notification, it won't do what you want because silent web push is still being shown.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/silent

There is a userVisibleOnly setting that can be set to false which means you don't have to display a notification. However with Chrome when you try to disable this Chrome does not allow it.
https://tests.peter.sh/push-message-generator/

Come join us in our discord server and learn more about our community:
https://onesignal.com/onesignal-developers

Answer (score 0):

how to trigger an event when a web notification is displayed in React.js. I want to update the ui when a new web push notification is received from OneSignal. I am using the npm package of OneSignal

```
import OneSignal from "react-onesignal";

export async function runOneSignalOnLogin(data) {
  await OneSignal.init({
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ONE_SIGNAL_ID,
    allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
  });
  OneSignal.showSlidedownPrompt();
  OneSignal.setExternalUserId(id);
  OneSignal.on("notificationDisplay", function (val) {
    console.log("Value:", val);
  });
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33326116)